# PHP- HTML parsing :: How can be taken charset value of webpage with simple html dom parser?

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom, php-parser

PHP:: How can be taken charset value of webpage  with simple [html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (utf-8, windows-255, etc..)?

remark: its have to be done with html dom parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

**Example1 webpage charset input:**

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

**result:utf-8**

---

---

**Example2 webpage charset input:**

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-255" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

**result:windows-255**

### Edit:

**I try this (but its not works):**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$el=$html->find('meta[content]',0);
echo $el->charset;
```

What should be change?
(I know that $el->charset not working)

Thanks

Comment: Run an xpath query for `//meta[@http-equiv="Content-Type"]/@content`.  You'll have to parse the attribute value yourself.

Comment: @Frank SimpleHTMLDom cant do Xpath

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives that actually use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to match the string using a regular expression (I hope you have PCRE...).

```
$el=$html->find('meta[http-equiv=Content-Type]',0)
$fullvalue = $el->content;
preg_match('/charset=(.+)/', $fullvalue, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Not very robust, but should work.

Comment: Thanks! I fix a bit and its works see my answer fix.

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$el=$html->find('meta[content]',0);
$fullvalue = $el->content;
preg_match('/charset=(.+)/', $fullvalue, $matches);
echo substr($matches[0], strlen("charset="));

Comment: **Don't do that**, I made a mistake. It should be `$matches[1]`. That makes it a lot faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dd = new DOMDocument;
$dd->loadHTML($data);
foreach ($dd->getElementsByTagName("meta") as $m) {
    if (strtolower($m->getAttribute("http-equiv")) == "content-type") {
        $v = $m->getAttribute("content");
        if (preg_match("#.+?/.+?;\\s?charset\\s?=\\s?(.+)#i", $v, $m))
            echo $m[1];
    }
}
```

Note that the DOM extension implicitly converts all the data to UTF-8.

Comment: Now that's a bit more robust than what I wrote... :)

Comment: Thanks for this option, because its very important to have utf-8 data.

Comment: @Mva yeah, Content-Type is sometimes written "Content-type". At least in the http headers, case doesn't matter.

Comment: DomDocument not convert proper text always to utf-8. I still working to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks for MvanGeest answer - I just fix a bit and its works perfect.**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$el=$html->find('meta[content]',0);
$fullvalue = $el->content;
preg_match('/charset=(.+)/', $fullvalue, $matches);
echo substr($matches[0], strlen("charset="));
```

Comment: Weird... it's working for me. You don't need the `substr` though... just `$matches[1]`. I tested it using Google.