# How can I get html webpage charset encode from html as string and not as dom?

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

How can I get html webpage charset encode from html as string and not as dom?

I get html string like that:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all (string pattern, string subject, array matches, int flags)
```

but i dont know regex, and I need to find out webpage charset (UTF-8/windows-255/etc..)
Thanks,

Comment: You should check the HTTP header for a character encoding first and only if missing check the HTML after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

preg_match('~charset=([-a-z0-9_]+)~i',$html,$charset);

Comment: this seems to suppose that `$html` contains the http header, which it does not.

Comment: Please no. What if I happen to be parsing a page that explains how to define the encoding of a page?...

Comment: That's assuming it happens before. `meta` can come after the `title` tag, an old `meta` tag may be commented out, etc etc. This is also not a good solution because the HTTP headers have priority.

Comment: I will concede to commented out tags,  But overall, he asked for a regex given his current code which uses file_get_contents() to get the html. That is what I gave him.

Comment: Thanks this exactly what i need, after i check your regex works great!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to check the Content-type header.

```
//add error handling
$f = fopen($url, "r");
$md = stream_get_meta_data($f);
$wd = $md["wrapper_data"];
foreach($wd as $response) {
    if (preg_match('/^content-type: .+?/.+?;\\s?charset=([^;"\\s]+|"[^;"]+")/i',
             $response, $matches) {
         $charset = $matches[1];
         break;
    }
}
$data = stream_get_contents($f);
```

You can then fallback on the `meta` element. That's been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356067/php-html-parsing-how-can-be-taken-charset-value-of-webpage-with-simple-html/3356168).

More complex version of header parsing to please the audience:

```
if (preg_match('~^content-type: .+?/[^;]+?(.*)~i', $response, $matches)) {
    if (preg_match_all('~;\\s?(?P<key>[^()<>@,;:\"/[\\]?={}\\s]+)'.
            '=(?P<value>[^;"\\s]+|"[^;"]+")\\s*~i', $matches[1], $m)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($m['key']); $i++) {
            if (strtolower($m['key'][$i]) == "charset") {
                $charset = trim($m['value'][$i], '"');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happened to pattern delimiters and case sensitivity?

Comment: regex has no delims and that greedy capture is gonna give a lot more than you want back

Comment: why  dont you use file_get_contents instead fopen?
I need to get html to other tesks after

Comment: @Crayon I forgot the delimiters, but I had non-greedy quantifiers there all the time.

Comment: @Yosef Because I needed to get the headers for the request. `file_get_contents` returns a string immediately so you have to change to fetch them.

Comment: really? well what do you call (.*) then?

Comment: @Crayon: greedy but it will not eat a newline.

Comment: @Crayon That's greedy, but it's the last thing in the expression; it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Crayon It will be, unless the server is violating the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @Crayon I think you're mistaking HTTP headers for HTML data.

Comment: @mvds Damn you and your references :p All right, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Artefacto: since you're getting the points here.. is the charset always the first parameter? ;-)

Comment: @mvds Ah, I've already hit the cap a few hours ago. I'll fix it, though.

Answer (score 0):

you *could* use

```
mb_detect_encoding($html);
```

but it is generally a bad idea. Better use curl instead and look at the Content-Type header.

Comment: Then maybe *"use curl instead and look at the Content-Type header"*